# parse 1.11 PFACL has no member setPublicReadAccess

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, acl

i started off on the demo app from https://github.com/kwkhaw/Layer-Parse-iOS-Swift-Example which uses 1.8 but in my main app i simply went with that most up to date one, which for me is 1.11.

but that gives me the issue in the title and in the image below. i'm new to parse. is there a replacement? how do i maintain functionality in the new version?

[image: problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no longer a setter function, it's a var, so you need to change to:

```
defaultACL.publicReadAccess = true
```

Comment: publicReadAccess has now been renamed to getPublicReadAccess

Comment: getPublicReadAccess is now hasPublicReadAccess